# Why doesn't this dataset generated from a numpy array using timeseries_dataset_from_array have a defined shape?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a `pandas` dataframe which I convert to a `numpy` array in order to generate a `tensorflow` dataset:

```
dataset = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    data=df,
    targets=df,
    sequence_length=100,
    batch_size=1,
    shuffle=False)
```

(targets are just dummy values for now)

When I try to train this model I get errors like `ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape (None, None) to a Tensor.`. I suspect these are caused by the fact that my dataset's dimensions are not understood:

[image]

But why is it that the shape of the dataset is `(None, None, 7)` when the shape of `df.values` is `(1740,7)`?

Answer (score 0):

The third dimension (which here is visually represented as dimension 0) is the batch. So your true first tensorspec is `(BATCH_SIZE, SEQUENCE_LENGTH, FEATURES)` or (1, 100, 7).

The targets matrix should not also be set to df as the network will not learn from this setup. None is an acceptable argument if you just want to explore the dataloader.

Depending on your usecase, you might try to set a single column as a target. Don't forget to call `.to_numpy()` on data and targets.

In that case, the BatchDataset will be `((BATCH, SEQ, FEATS), (BATCH, SEQ))`. This is because targets are stored as a vector within the batch. It should look like `((None, None, FEATS), (None, None))` when done correctly. If you don't get FEATS then something may be wrong.